# Embed xml into dll

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

For my UI system, which is similar to WPF but written cross plattform with OpenGL, i need to embed the xml files into the DLL which are used to layout the user controls. <strike>The problem is: By default MonoTouch does not support embedding any file into a dll and afaik there is only one solution which solves this: Embed the xml into a `*.cs` file and compile it.</strike>

Now, this is a task which doesn't make any fun if you do it per hand each time, so the question is how is the best way to achieve this for both, **Visual Studio and MonoDevelop**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MonoTouch does not compile C# code, it uses the `smcs` compiler. That's the same compiler being used for Mono for Android and, originally, for Moonlight.

That `smcs` compiler is able to embed files into assemblies, it's doing so the BCL (e.g. globalization files for mscorlib.dll) and that was an **important** requirement for XAML (in Moonlight).

Comment: I read about embedded resource support a time ago, but you are correct, it seems to have been changed( Just look at google, you going to find a lot of stuff about this topic which says it wont work ). I'm going to test it and give you feedback it it does work. Thank you

Comment: @FelixK. Do no believe everything from Google ;-) Moonlight predates MonoTouch creation, used the same `smcs` compiler (the `s` is for Silverlight) and required embedding XAML files into assemblies.

Comment: It's working, annoying because i'm sure i tested it once and it did not.

Comment: @FelixK. if you ever figure out the condition where it did not work then please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com Thanks!